# How can we add events like on focus to an element created using document.createElement() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I would like to add an on focus event to the text box:

```
 var el = document.createElement('input');
           el.type = 'text';
     
             el.setAttribute("id",'suggest22');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var el = document.createElement('input');
el.type = 'text';
el.setAttribute('id','suggest22');

el.onclick = function(){alert(this.id);}
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/GN2tP/

Answer (score 2):

```
el.onfocus = function() {
   // Focused.
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/uWpDt/).

You could also use `addEventListener('focus', function() { ... }, false)` in standards compliant browsers and `attachEvent('onfocus', function() { ... })` in < IE9.

Also, you can use `id` property as a shortcut to setting the element's `id` attribute.

You also shouldn't mix single (`'`) and double (`"`). Use one or the other, consistently.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the standard compliant alternative. (*the `attachEvent` version should have the prefix **on** though, `onfocus` to the event name*)

Comment: phew... i saw the corrected version and was not sure if you had edited or i had misread it the first time :)